# Unable to run query java mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I am not able to run a query in a mysql database. throws exception : 
The database name is correct still unable to understand whats the issue
Running in Java Eclipse. Using Mysql Jar : `external/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar`

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'autodist'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3436)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)`
My Code :

```
try {
  DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/autodist","root","1234");

  System.out.println(conn.toString());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| autodist           |     |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: try to create a table inside your database say tablename and then check my code.

Comment: I tried that too , even created another user but still same

Comment: go inside my sql and check

Comment: i have edited the answer plz chk and if after trying it doesnt work please verify previliges.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/autodist?"
              + "user=root&password=1234");

PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("select * from <tablename>");
```

Then:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Tried still Same Exception

Comment: `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'DBName'`

Comment: If you just need to know if a db exists so you won't get an error when you try to create it, simply use  `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBName;`

Comment: Thanks @khakishoiab for helping. I found out That there were multiple mysql instance running ( no idea how :o )and it was connecting to that where no databases present, Thus giving the error.

Comment: in case of multiple mysql instance running this can happen.